# SOLVED Grails HelloWorld brakes down before i even start

Tags: exception, grails

[Urlmappings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7az0.png)
[HelloController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ML07.png)

Pls help i followed the "Hello-World-Instruction" on the grails homepage exactly but it throws an error (before i even start it breaks ;D)
tried looking for solution maybe it has to do with my Java Path?

I finished the helloWorld Tut on [Tutorial](https://docs.grails.org/5.1.7/guide/gettingStarted.html#aHelloWorldExample) then put "grails run-app" into the shell and then Error!

Linux debian based Distro

Grails Version: 5.1.2

JVM Version: 11.0.1

Groovy Version: 4.0.1 JVM: 11.0.14
[Error creating bean 'compositeViewResolver'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHo9W.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8u5I.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrQzC.png)

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use Groovy 3.0.7?

Comment: same result ! :/

Comment: Maybe you can provide the whole stacktrace of the error?

Comment: didnt i do that with the image ?! i ran it with "--stracktrace" it shows the same output!

Comment: "didnt i do that with the image ?" - That doesn't look like the whole stack.  Can you share a copy of an app which demonstrates the problem?  Also if you could link to whatever hello world instruction on our web page you are referencing, that might help too.  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: i provided the additional Infos above now! and thanks to all trying to help!

Comment: You are likely experiencing the issue described at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/12460.

Comment: thx m8 worked! Problem solving: update to grails 5.1.7 and i needed to set grails version in gradle.properties to 5.1.7 (since i created it with 5.1.6 i guess)

Comment: "thx m8 worked!" - It might be good to post your solution as an answer and accept it.  Changing the subject to include "SOLVED" may help, but that won't cause the question to show up as having an accepted solution in search results.